# Open and redraw fragment with Google Map from AsyncTask invoked in another fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

I have an android app with Navigation Drawer and two fragments. One of them contains Google Map. The click on the button (`findRoute` method) in another fragment invokes AsyncTask (`RouteAsyncTask`) to get the coordinates of the route. Now I want to draw the route on the map, so I have to open the first fragment with Google Map and update my map in the `onPostExecute` method of the AsyncTask. How can I do this?

This is my setup of fragments and onClick method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpToolbar();
        setUpNavDrawer();
        setUpContentFragment(MapFragment.class);
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                Class fragmentClass;

                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_item_1:
                        mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
                        fragmentClass = MapFragment.class;
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_item_2:
                        mCurrentSelectedPosition = 1;
                        fragmentClass = RoutesFragment.class;
                        break;                     
                    default:
                        fragmentClass = MapFragment.class;
                        break;
                }
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                setUpContentFragment(fragmentClass);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void setUpContentFragment(Class fragmentClass) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Ex: ", ex);
        }
        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
    }
   ...
public void findRoute(View view) {
        ...
        RouteAsyncTask routeAsyncTask = new RouteAsyncTask(this, urlString);
        routeAsyncTask.execute();
}
```

This is my RouteAsyncTask:

```
public class RouteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<LatLng>> {
    public static ArrayList<LatLng> polyline = new ArrayList<>();
    String urlString;
    Context context;

    public RouteAsyncTask(Context context, String urlString) {
        this.context = context;
        this.urlString = urlString;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<LatLng> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ...
        return listGeopoints;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<LatLng> latLngs) {
        super.onPostExecute(latLngs);
        if (latLngs != null) {
            polyline = latLngs;
        }
    }
```

And here is my `update` method to draw route in `MapFragment`:

```
public void update() {
        if (mMap != null && RouteAsyncTask.polyline != null) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = RouteAsyncTask.polyline;
            PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);
            for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
            }
            mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
        }
    }
```

Comment: view can not change in background because of view comes in create activity and you are going to update that view in background so this is not possible in background

Comment: But you can apply to all UI elements without any restrictions in the `onPostExecute` method

Comment: you need to load data in side Fragment or activity on create and then you can update view on map. this technique make app slow but this is correct with my way if there are any solution post here ..

Comment: some time this gives you correct answer and some time not . i have worked on map on post i used but this was not success

Comment: if you have values in double and you need to display any kind of view like textview this is not possible . either you u convert double to string or not ...

Comment: "values in double" 
What does it mean? What do you talking about?

Comment: if you have some values in double like location() method some other values which is assigne in double that cant set to any view.

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand my problem... I don't need to display any kind of view like textview. I need to draw line on the map.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99211/discussion-between-ksenia-and-amitsharma).